# JavaScript Wrap Around Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looking for some information from some front end experts on how to go about creating a custom wrap around js carousel gallery. The idea is simple really I have a carousel of images, text, or whatever and when I get to the end I want it to wrap around. I don't want the content to simply fadeIn and out to the next piece of content. This is a gallery of div's currently but suppose it's images or whatever have you.

**HTML**

```
<div id="outside-container">
  <div id="inside-container" class="cf">
     <div class="items" id="item1"></div>
     <div class="items" id="item2"></div>
     <div class="items" id="item3"></div>
     <div class="items" id="item4"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="directions">
  <h4 id="left-button">Left</h4>
  <h4 id="right-button">Right</h4>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#outside-container{
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  height: 125px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
#inside-container{
  display: block;
  width: 800px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

.items{
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
}
#item1{ background: green; }
#item2{ background: red; }
#item3{ background: blue; }
#item4{ background: yellow; }

#directions{
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#left-button, #right-button{
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

**JS**

```
var move = 0;
$("#left-button").click(function(){
    move += 200;
    $("#inside-container").animate({
      marginLeft: move+"px"
    }, 500);
});

$("#right-button").click(function(){

    move -= 200;
    $("#inside-container").animate({
      marginLeft: move+"px"
    }, 500);
});
```

Here is the [codepen](http://codepen.io/johnstew/pen/aldDK). So to sum all this up. I am asking for a way to create an infite loop for a gallery. I have always programmed these sorts of things to come to an end and then the user has to go back the other way. If this sounds confusing follow check out the codepen. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go

http://codepen.io/nickavi/pen/cpFCE

But for the love of god, please don't use jQuery animate... at least add velocity.js to it, or the GSAP plugin, you don't even have to alter your JS you just add it in and it replaces the animate function with a more efficient one.

Cheers JBSTEW

Comment: Only used jquery animate for demo purposes. Thanks for this. Your really great. whats your website? nickavi.com. Thats cool. Good for you man. Your great. Thanks again. TweenMax for days...

Comment: Anything that uses requestAnimationFrame (like GSAP) should kick jQuery's butt on performance unless they finally implemented RAF in JQ 2+.

Answer (score 1):

First set move to the default slider and margin reset amount:

```
var move = 200;
```

Then, set the container margin to slide left by the `move` amount:

```
var margin_reset = (move * -1) + 'px'
$("#inside-container").css('margin-left', margin_reset);
```

Then, adjust the animation margin slide using `move` variable again, and execute a function when the animation is complete that moves the last/first item to the beginning/end of the container using prepend/append.

```
$("#left-button").click(function(){
    $("#inside-container").animate({
      marginLeft: 0
    }, 500, function() {
      $(this).prepend( $(this).find('.items:last') )
        .css('margin-left', margin_reset);
  });
});

$("#right-button").click(function(){
    $("#inside-container").animate({
      marginLeft: (move * -2) +"px"
    }, 500, function() {
      $(this).append( $(this).find('.items:first') )
        .css('margin-left', margin_reset);
  });    
});
```

To avoid an initial draw jump, you could change the default css `#inside-container` as:

```
#inside-container{
    ...
    margin-left: -200px;
}
```

see: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BsniH)

Comment: Thanks for the answer this makes sense. I am going to try this on a much larger scale with images and see how it goes.

Comment: For a slight different variation to the above, instead of adding margin-left: -200px to the css you could do an javascript onload that would move the last element to the front and add the -200px padding.  This would ensure that the first element in the list is visible (instead of hidden to the left) and also avoid the onload jump of the slider.

Comment: Lots of ways to handle this and this is basically the way I wrote my first carousel (which I'm still proud of) but for best performance I'd opt for the following things. Use the scrollOffset property and requestAnimationFrame for the repositioning. Scrolling doesn't really have an impact on CSS reflow calcs as far as I know and RAF is a drastic improvement in browser animation. Also rebuilding the entire block of items with item buffers on either side at the end of every animation probably actually perform better and is easier for handling page slides of multiple items.